# List all files containing a string between two specific strings (not on the same line)

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to recursively find all `.md` files of the current directory that contain the “Narrow No-Break Space” `U+202F` Unicode character between the two strings `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, possibly (and in fact essentially) not on the same line as `U+202F`.

A great addition would be to replace such `U+202F`s by normal spaces.

I already find a way to extract text between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` with [a Python regexp](https://regex101.com/r/92HcFA/1) (which I used to find easier for multi-line substitutions. I tried to use it just to list files with this pattern (planning to afterwards chain with `grep` to at least get the files where this pattern contains `U+202F`) but my attempts with:

```py
def finds_files_whose_contents_match_a_regex(filename):
    textfile = open(filename, 'r')
    filetext = textfile.read()
    textfile.close()
    matches = re.findall("\\begin{document}\s*(.*?)\s*\\end{document}", filetext)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".md"):
            filename=os.path.join(root, filename)
            finds_files_whose_contents_match_a_regex(filename)
```

but I got unintelligible (for me) errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test-bis.py", line 14, in <module>
    finds_files_whose_contents_match_a_regex(filename)
  File "./test-bis.py", line 8, in finds_files_whose_contents_match_a_regex
    matches = re.findall("\\begin{document}\s*(.*?)\s*\\end{document}", filetext)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/re.py", line 240, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/re.py", line 303, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/sre_compile.py", line 788, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/sre_parse.py", line 955, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/sre_parse.py", line 444, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/sre_parse.py", line 526, in _parse
    code = _escape(source, this, state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/sre_parse.py", line 427, in _escape
    raise source.error("bad escape %s" % escape, len(escape))
re.error: bad escape \e at position 27
```

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: What I tried so far added

Comment: You should be using `MULTILINE` mode?https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE

Comment: I have already answered with a Javascript example by the time I have seen your edit. You can convert my code to Python then.

Comment: Maybe the errors are unintelligible to you, but please provide them anyway; we can probably explain to you what they mean.

Comment: @tripleee Error message added

Comment: @MatBailie Adding the `re.MULTILINE` flag (`matches = re.findall("\\begin{document}\s*(.*?)\s*\\end{document}", filetext, flags=(re.MULTILINE))`) doesn't help.

Comment: To find a Unicode code point, the file must be decoded with the correct encoding.  What encoding are the .md files encoded in?  Is it consistent for all .md files?  `open` will use a default (likely `'utf8'` on *nix), but it might not be what the files are encoded in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are correctly reading or decoding an encoded file...

I would do something along these lines.

```
from pathlib import Path 
import re 

p=Path('/tmp')  # Use your root path here

def replace_non_break_spaces(fn):
    with open(fn,"r") as f:
        cont=f.read()
    
    cont_update=re.sub(r"\\begin{document}[\s\S]*?\\end{document}", 
        lambda m: m.group(0).replace("\u202F", "!"), cont)
    
    if cont!=cont_update:
        # at this point, write 'cont_update' back to the same file. 
        # File is only updated if the re.sub changes the string
        pass

for fn in (x for x in p.glob("**/*.md") if x.is_file()):
    replace_non_break_spaces(fn)
```

Given your [example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/92HcFA/1) (which I modified as seen):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=7cm]{geometry}
  <=there are u202F there
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Du texte aligné à droite :
  <=there are u202F there
\raggedleft
cet exemple ne brille sans
doute pas par sa complexité.

Clair, non ? 
\end{document}
```

The result is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=7cm]{geometry}
  <=there are u202F there
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Du texte aligné à droite :
!!<=there are u202F there
\raggedleft
cet exemple ne brille sans
doute pas par sa complexité.

Clair, non!?
\end{document}
```

(The non-breaking spaces are replaced with `!` for clarity...)

---

From the comment *running python test.py doesn't change test.md*:

```
from pathlib import Path 
import re 

p=Path('/tmp')  # Use your root path here

def replace_non_break_spaces(fn):
    with open(fn,"r") as f:
        cont=f.read()
    
    cont_update=re.sub(r"\\begin{document}[\s\S]*?\\end{document}", 
        lambda m: m.group(0).replace("\u202F", "!"), cont)
    
    if cont!=cont_update:
        print(f"Updating {fn}")
        # make a backup...
        with open(f"{fn}.bak", "w") as f:
            f.write(cont)
        with open(fn,"w") as f:
            f.write(cont_update)

for fn in (x for x in p.glob("**/*.md") if x.is_file()):
    replace_non_break_spaces(fn)
```

**CAREFUL!!!** This code will recursively change every `.md` file in a tree (it does make backups as updated.)

Comment: If I store the Python code and the example text in `/tmp/test.py` and `/tmp/test.md` respectively, running `python test.py` doesn't change `test.md`. I double -checked that `test.md` is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: You need to add the code to write the file back. I can add that...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by splitting and joining your string. A Javascript code for it looks like this:

```js
function seekAndReplace(input, start, end, from, to) {
    let items = input.split(start);
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if ((i > 0) || (input.startsWith(start))) {
            let indexOfEnd = items[i].indexOf(end);
            if (indexOfEnd >= 0) {
                let first = items[i].substring(0, indexOfEnd).replaceAll(from, to);
                let second = items[i].substring(indexOfEnd);
                items[i] = first + second;
            }
        }
    }
    return items.join(start);
}

let input = `;
ss;dsd;sdk;start
skhksjdfsdfsljsd;
dslkdhsfkdshs;asd;a
sa;jadlkdas;askl
;dalsj;asj
endk;ds
s;sddsk;`;

console.log(seekAndReplace(input, "start", "end", ";", ":"))
```

You can implement something similar in the language of your choice. When that's reliable, just implement something that loops your files and calls this for its content. If the content changes, save.

Comment: Thanks but, not easy to translate (and `js2py` doesn't work).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé this code is not that long. You will just need to look into Pythonic alternatives. String split: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp Starts with: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_startswith.asp String index: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/index Substring: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-substring-a-string-in-python/ Replace: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp Join: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp

Answer (score 1):

The below code removes the target character found **only** between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in "*basename*.md" files, and writes the new content to "*basename*.md.new".  I used a visible character (U+2014 EM DASH) to make it more obvious.

Note that the encoding of the .md files **must be known and consistent**.  UTF-8 encoding is common on *nix, but not Windows.  It is a good practice to be explicit about the encoding since the default varies by OS.

Also note that `re.DOTALL` is needed for `.` to match newlines.  Default is to match all character *except* newlines.

```py
import os
import re
from time import 
target = '\u2014'
# target = '\u202f'

def remove_non_breaking_space_in_documents(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf8') as textfile:
        filetext = textfile.read()
    updated = re.sub(r'\\begin{document}.*?\\end{document}',
                     lambda m: m.group(0).replace(target, ' '),
                     filetext, flags=re.DOTALL)
    # Update file if it changed
    if updated != filetext:
        with open(filename+'.new', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
            f.write(updated)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.md'):
            filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
            remove_non_breaking_space_in_documents(filename)
```

test.md

```
\begin{document}
some—stuff
and some—more stuff
\end{document}
# comment—outside documents
\begin{document}
even more—stuff
and some—more stuff
\end{document}
```

test.md.new

```
\begin{document}
some stuff
and some more stuff
\end{document}
# comment—outside documents
\begin{document}
even more stuff
and some more stuff
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Denis Not with the above code, you didn't.  Make sure you are using the code I posted *exactly* and not incorporated incorrectly in your own code before reporting an error.  `updated` is used in 3 places and clearly defined before used.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means you did not quote the regex correctly. This is a bit of a design wart in Python; the backslash has one meaning in quoted strings, and another in regular expressions, which however need to be passed inside quoted strings.

The usual remedy these days is to use the `r"..."` "raw string" in Python for regular expressions; it simply makes the backslash a normal character as far as Python is concerned, inside this string, and so you don't need to wrap everything in a second layer of escaping backslashes.

```
    matches = re.findall(r"\\begin{document}\s*(.*?)\s*\\end{document}", filetext)
                         ^
```

An equivalent but murkier solution would be to double all the backslashes.

```
    matches = re.findall("\\\\begin{document}\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\\\end{document}", filetext)
```

In a future version of Python, you will even get a syntax error if you try to use invalid escapes like `\s` or `\z` in a regular string.

In some more detail, Python reserves sequences like `\t` and `\n` for representing tab and newline, respectively (there's a handful more, and of course `\\` to denote a literal backslash), and any other use of a lone backslash followed by a character is semantically murky, and will be turned into an error. (The legacy behavior was simply to ignore the backslash.)

Inside a regular expression, you want sequences like `\s` or `\d` or `\[` or `\.` (and many more) which have special meaning to the regex engine, but these have to be represented as `\\s` or `\\d` or `\\[` or `\\.`, respectively, in a regular Python string, so that what the regular expression parser sees, once Python has parsed the string into its internal representation, is a regular backslash followed by another character.